# SQL to count down days for items to expire

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I need help with an SQL query that will count down days for an item to expire at present the SQL query shows the date of expiration but I need the days counting down as well. The count down must show how many days the item has before being deleted eg. 3,2,1 while keeping the expiration date. Can anyone help me?

Below is my code:

```
SELECT [Sales Order Number], 
       [Customer Code], 
       [Customer Name], 
       [Total Weight], 
       [Order Total (Incl)], 
       [Account Terms], 
       [Credit Limit], 
       Status, 
       Autoindex, 
       [Document State],
       Date,
       CASE[Document State]
              WHEN 'Unprocessed' THEN DATEADD(day, 14, Date)
              WHEN 'Partially Processed' THEN DATEADD(day, 7, Date)
         END AS[Expiration Date]
FROM ZS_vwSOA_PendingApproval 
WHERE[Document State] IN('Unprocessed', 'Partially Processed')
```

Comment: please look at this link and rephrase your question and also tag the version of SQL..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: please, be more specific. what kind of countdown?

Comment: @gofr1 I have edited the post, The count down must show the number of days to go. Eg. for an unprocessed item the item will expire in 14 days so it need it show 14, 13, 12

Comment: Put your case statement into datediff function like: DATEDIFF(day,case...end, GETDATE()) it will count days between expiration date and current date.

Comment: @gofr1 The Expiration Date field is a temp field and cannot be picked up in SQL

Comment: As I say, put your case statement in datediff, it will be another column. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comments, use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
SELECT [Sales Order Number], 
       [Customer Code], 
       [Customer Name], 
       [Total Weight], 
       [Order Total (Incl)], 
       [Account Terms], 
       [Credit Limit], 
       Status, 
       Autoindex, 
       [Document State],
       Date,
       CASE[Document State]
              WHEN 'Unprocessed' THEN DATEADD(day, 14, Date)
              WHEN 'Partially Processed' THEN DATEADD(day, 7, Date)
         END AS[Expiration Date],
       DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),
       CASE[Document State]
              WHEN 'Unprocessed' THEN DATEADD(day, 14, Date)
              WHEN 'Partially Processed' THEN DATEADD(day, 7, Date)
         END) as [Countdown]
FROM ZS_vwSOA_PendingApproval 
WHERE[Document State] IN('Unprocessed', 'Partially Processed')
```